# Angular 2 - Is it possible for dynamically loaded data to persist when navigating through multiple pages on the app?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm working on an angular 2 app with multiple pages and components for each page. The app deals with large amounts of content. I would like to navigate through the app without having the pages to refresh when I come back to it. For example, I have an uploads page where I can upload single or multiple files and also view recently uploaded files. When I navigate to the homepage and then come back to uploads page, I am no longer able to view recently uploaded files. Is there a way to still render all those files on uploads page without having to make calls to the server every time?

Answer (score 2):

You may create a Store service, which will keep data either in memory or even in local storage in Browser, and check if data is already available use it or fetch from server.

Having said that there are multiple ways of creating cache of your data, I don't think angular gives anything inherently for this.

[data caching in SPA](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=data%20caching%20in%20SPA)

Hope this helps!!